# Bananian and iPod sync with Rhythmbox

Tags: ipod, rhythmbox, banana-pi

I'am using a Banana Pi Pro with [Bananian OS](https://www.bananian.org/), which is a Debian 8 installation, using armhf packages. Trying to synchronise my iPod classic 6g with Rhythmbox fails.

I've installed a xfce desktop environment

```
apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-power-manager hicolor-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme 
apt-get install lightdm
apt-get install xorg
apt-get install usbmount
```

and Rhythmbox

```
apt-get install rhythmbox
apt-get install rhythmbox-plugins
```

The iPod plugin is activated, but my iPod is not recognized by Rhythmbox. Using [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/index.php?title=Home) the iPod is recognized and all songs with ratings and playcounts are listed (the internal player is not able to play music from the iPod, but that's another issue I think and should not be related to Rhythmbox).

On my Ubuntu 14.04 machine the iPod works out of the box with Rhythmbox. So it should work in principle.

Did I miss any packages to install?